# Remove/ignore entries with non overlapping number sequences (not date sequences)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I have entries which can form a sequence based on period type and a from / to value.

Period type can be "W" (weeks possible range 1-53), "M" (month 1-12) and some special types but within a year and always with a range 1..x

An entry either can cover a (complete) range or there can be multiple entries which cover the range (with or without gaps and not necessarily the complete range). Also the sequence can start somewhere within the allowed range.

So valid would be:

```
W    1   12
W   13   25
W   26   52
```

Not valid would be

```
W    1   12
W   11   53 <-- overlap
```

Now I need a way to filter/ignore the valid ones an only display the invalid ones. Unfortunately it has to be in SQL because it's for a reporting tool which doesn't support any scripting.

In the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2c32/1 the entries with W 1-53 are the invalid ones.

(the result lines with "NULL" are only for visual spacing)

Comment: you can do the self join (Left join) `On A.Customer = B.Customer AND A.Key1 = B.Key1 AND A.Key2 = B.Key2 AND A.Key3 != B.Keys3 AND A.Period = B.Period WHERE B.PFrom < A.PTo`

Comment: @LONG It won't be a left join anymore if you put `B` in the where clause.

Comment: In your sample in the sqlfiddle could you clarify which are the key columns over which you want to apply the rule above?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you! am thinking just `select B.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a version that uses the LEAD window function to get the next range and compare's current range with next range.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed8e3/11)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [customer] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [key1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [key2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [key3] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [period] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [period_from] [int] NULL,
    [period_to] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([customer], [key1], [key2], [key3], [period], [period_from], [period_to])
VALUES 
(N'A         ', N'XYZ       ', N'123       ', N'000       ', N'W', 1, 53), 
(N'A         ', N'XYZ       ', N'123       ', N'111       ', N'W', 1, 53),
(N'A         ', N'ABC       ', N'123       ', N'000       ', N'Q', 1, 2), 
(N'A         ', N'ABC       ', N'123       ', N'333       ', N'Q', 3, 3), 
(N'A         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'CCC       ', N'W', 1, 20),
(N'A         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'DDD       ', N'W', 21, 30),
(N'A         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'EEE       ', N'W', 31, 53),

(N'B         ', N'XYZ       ', N'123       ', N'000       ', N'W', 1, 53), 
(N'B         ', N'XYZ       ', N'123       ', N'111       ', N'W', 1, 53),
(N'B         ', N'ABC       ', N'123       ', N'000       ', N'Q', 1, 2), 
(N'B         ', N'ABC       ', N'123       ', N'333       ', N'Q', 3, 3), 
(N'B         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'CCC       ', N'W', 1, 20),
(N'B         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'DDD       ', N'W', 21, 30),
(N'B         ', N'YYY       ', N'321       ', N'EEE       ', N'W', 31, 53)
```

**Query 1**:

```
    -- This solution assumes that the unique keys are (customer, key1, key2 and period)
    -- Adjust based on your needs
    ;WITH WithNext AS (select 
      *, 
      LEAD(period_from) OVER(PARTITION BY customer, key1, key2, period ORDER BY period_from, period_to) AS next_period_from,
      LEAD(period_to) OVER(PARTITION BY customer, key1, key2, period ORDER BY period_from, period_to) AS next_period_to
      from Test
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM Test t
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM WithNext w 
       WHERE 
         w.customer = t.customer 
         AND w.key1 = t.key1
         AND w.key2 = t.key2
         AND w.period = t.period
         AND (w.next_period_from BETWEEN w.period_from AND w.period_to)
      )
    ORDER BY customer, key1, key2, period
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed8e3/11/0)**:

```
|   customer |       key1 |       key2 |       key3 | period | period_from | period_to |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|--------|-------------|-----------|
| A          | ABC        | 123        | 000        |      Q |           1 |         2 |
| A          | ABC        | 123        | 333        |      Q |           3 |         3 |
| A          | YYY        | 321        | CCC        |      W |           1 |        20 |
| A          | YYY        | 321        | DDD        |      W |          21 |        30 |
| A          | YYY        | 321        | EEE        |      W |          31 |        53 |
| B          | ABC        | 123        | 000        |      Q |           1 |         2 |
| B          | ABC        | 123        | 333        |      Q |           3 |         3 |
| B          | YYY        | 321        | CCC        |      W |           1 |        20 |
| B          | YYY        | 321        | DDD        |      W |          21 |        30 |
| B          | YYY        | 321        | EEE        |      W |          31 |        53 |
```

Comment: Thank you! LEAD does the trick. The only change I had to make was WHERE EXISTS instead of WHERE NOT EXISTS since I need the invalid ones.